# Bunching subscribers to in-flight async requests - RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have some functions that call other async functions and return the results as Observables. These functions can be subscribed to many times throughout different parts of my application at the same time.

I would like to prevent running the async function again if it's still "in-flight", however still emit the value to all subscribers once it completes. If not in-flight it should call the async function again.

Is there a better pattern for this; am I approaching this the wrong way?

What I have done is create a subject for storing the result, and a flag for keeping track of the in-flight request.

```js
  inFlight = false;
  subject$ = new Subject<any>();
  requestsLog = [];

  getThing() {
    console.log("(getThing) running?", this.inFlight);
    return iif(() => this.inFlight, this.subject$, this.fakeAsyncRequest$())
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        tap(date => console.log("(getThing) get value", date)),
        tap(date => this.requestsLog.push(date))
      );
  }

  fakeAsyncRequest$ = () => {
    return of(new Date().toUTCString()).pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        console.log("(fakeAsyncRequest) request");
        this.requestsLog = []; // Reset things
        this.inFlight = true; // Set in flight flag
      }),
      delay(1500), // Simulate async delay
      tap(date => this.subject$.next(date)),
      finalize(() => {
        console.log("(fakeAsyncRequest) Done");
        this.inFlight = false;
      })
    );
  };

  smilutateMultiple() {
    // Simulate a few calls to this function
    this.getThing().subscribe();
    this.getThing().subscribe();
    this.getThing().subscribe();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getThing().subscribe();
    }, 500);
  }
```

I also tried to use a BehaviourSubject in combination with an ExhaustMap but the inner observable still gets called for each subscription to the observable.

```js
  private subject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
  public subjectObs$ = this.subject$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.fakeAsyncRequest()));

  fakeAsyncRequest = () => {
    console.log("call fake request", new Date().toUTCString());
    return this.http
    .get("https://www.reddit.com/hot.json")
    .pipe(delay(1000));
  };

  smilutateMultiple() {
    // Simulate a few subscriptions to this observable
    this.subjectObs$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing", thing));
    this.subjectObs$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing", thing));
    // Should be same request.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.subjectObs$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing", thing));
    }, 500);
    // Should be new request.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.subjectObs$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing", thing));
    }, 3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the [share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) operator. This "shares" the source observable with multiple subscribers.

This relates to the concepts of "hot vs cold" observables and "multicasting".

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akfcy5

```js
  public observable$ = this.fakeAsyncRequest$().pipe(share());

  private fakeAsyncRequest$() {
    return this.http.get("https://www.reddit.com/hot.json").pipe(
      tap(() => console.log("Call fake request at:", new Date().toUTCString())),
      delay(500)
    );
  }

  smilutateMultiple() {
    // Simulate a few subscriptions to this observable
    this.observable$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing 1", thing));
    this.observable$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing 2", thing));
    // Should be same request.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.observable$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing 3", thing));
    }, 500);
    // Should be new request.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.observable$.subscribe(thing => console.log("Thing 4", thing));
    }, 3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reactive JS module - RxJS is certainly the best way to avoid this. In RxJS, you can have a state which looks like below

```
export interface ProjectState extends EntityState<Project> {
    selectedProjectId: string;
    creating: boolean;
    created: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
    error: string;
}
```

In such a state, when you fire an action - LOAD_PROJECTS, the reducer will mark the flag "loading" to true. Now, in other parts of your application, you can subscribe to "projects' entities and "loading" flag. If loading flag is false, dispatch the LOAD_PROJECTS else do not dispatch.

The subscription to "projects" entities will ensure that the subscriber inside every component is called when your data is updated. Thus preventing any additional calls.

RxJS might seem complicated and complex in the beginning. However, it is one of the best structured library for sharing state across application.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a facade, use it to retrieve the data throughout different parts of your application and use the `exhaustMap` operator.

More information to the `exhaustMap` operator: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/exhaustMap

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. The way I understood it the exhaust should skip incoming subscriptions until the inner observable is completed. But In my case, it's calling the inner subscription function again.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akfcy5